# TypeScript. Keyword "this" in callbacks

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the simple TypeScript class. Here it is

```
class Test {
    myMethod() {
        this.func(this.callback);
    }

    private func(callback: Function) {
        console.log(this);
        callback();
    }

    private callback() {
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

And when I try to use this class so

```
new Roadkill.Web.Page.Test().myMethod();
```

I get the following output in console:

```
Test {} // output from func()
Window {...} // output from callback
```

As you can see 'usual' method `func` treats `this` as `Test` class as it  expected. But callback method named `callback` handles `this` as global object `Window` and it surprised me. Does anyone know how to use class `Test` and its members from callback method?

Comment: `this.func(this.callback.bind(this))`

Comment: The value of `this` is decided by the way you *call* the function. You're calling it as `callback()`, therefore there's no `this` context.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko thank you! It works!